# Trying to Create a Extractor program in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, extract

So I'm trying to create this program For A Game that will take mods in .zip form from a folder and extract them all in the game folder, this is the code I've got so far. I think The code of button2 can't get the folder's from the other button's I have tried several things but cant get it to work.

```
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Dim GameFolder As String
Dim ZipFolder As String


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Public Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim mypath As String
    Dim fname As String

    mypath = ZipFolder  ' Select zip location folder
    fname = Dir(mypath & "*.zip")  ' get first zip file
    Do While Len(fname) > 0
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fname, mypath)
        fname = Dir()   ' get next matching file
    Loop
End Sub

Public Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim fd As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog() ' Let the user select the Zip Folder
    Dim ZipFolder As String
    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        ZipFolder = fd.SelectedPath 'Set the Zipfolder string to the output of the FolderBrowser
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim fd As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog() 'Let the user select the game folder
    Dim GameFolder As String
    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        GameFolder = fd.SelectedPath 'Set the GameFolder string to the output of the FolderBrowser
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `Dim ZipFolder As String` in Button3_Click?

Comment: He should even remove `Dim GameFolder As String` in Button4_Click.

Comment: After Removing `Dim ZipFolder As String` and `Dim GameFolder As String` It still does not work, Nothing happens like before.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apart from the initial declarations at the top of your code,

remove all other occurrences of

```
Dim GameFolder As String
Dim ZipFolder As String
```

The reason is that when you declare them in subs, any code in the sub will use the local declaration in preference to the global one.

So, when you assign the dialog results to the variables in your current code, they only get assigned to the local variables, not the form wide variables.

Comment: It sort of works now, only when i select both file directories and click the install button (Button1), it says that it cant find the .zip file in the location of the debug .exe i dont really now what it means by that since it does say the name of the .zip file it found on my desktop.

Comment: I just got it to work :) I was being a retard, i just build the program and ran it outside of visual studio. Now it works Like a Charm!